# How to save my Kalanchoe blossfeldiana

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, succulents

I've had my kalanchoe blossfeldiana for about 3 years now, and I propagated one plant into 4 separate stems earlier in January. It flowered in the spring, but after the flowers went away the plant has been growing new baby leaves but all the old ones are dying. Is this normal, or is there something I can do to help it?

Note: I'd also like to point out that it gets a lot of sunshine due to living in California.

[image: The smaller plant]

[image: The bigger set of 3]

Comment: Do those pots have drainage holes?

Comment: Yes, both pots have drainage holes. The plant was originally thriving in the panda pot for 2 years before I decided to propagate them due to overgrowth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is perfectly natural and to be expected. - The old growth (from the original cutting) is damaged tissue and will die off naturally whilst the stock (the cutting) will produce new growth whilst it is rooting (which is also why new plants will sometimes die even after producing new growth if the compost is too moist, or if they are attacked by something, for example).